# Best approach of aligning text next to another element?

Tags: css

Well, usually when I need to align text next to box, I do it like this: 
https://codepen.io/Maartinshh/pen/yMdNrW , but I've heard its terrible mistake to use 
paddings and margins for this kinda of job. Is there an alternative?

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="text">Text</div>

.box{
  background-color:blue;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.text{
  padding-left: 80px; 
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Comment: use inline-block + vertical-align:middle on both div

Answer (score 1):

For your example, I would change display type to `inline-block`, and then use `vertical-align` property to center the text.

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

A second approach might be using `flexbox`. You can wrap both divs in a container and apply flex properties to it:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, but where's the difference in your version from "better code" point of view?

Comment: Using padding and margin with fixed values is awkward when you consider responsiveness. It also means that if you change the size of your div, or even font size, you'll need to update other values

Answer (score 0):

Use can use inline-block and vertical align.

```
.box{
  background-color:blue;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text{
   padding-left: 10px; 
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```